# QuickLink in UML Profile not displaying in Sparx enterprise Architect

Tags: profile, enterprise-architect

I am trying to add a new item to the 'quick link' menu in Sparx Enterprise Architect.

I have followed the instructions on the EA website:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/add_quick_linker_definition_to.html

and in despiration I have also tried a vanilla copy of the example from http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/quick_linker_example.html

I have a new profile with a new stereotype of 'quick' which extends the metaclass 'Class'. I have added a 'QuickLink' artefact and copied the below entries into it (from the example above):

Class,quick,,,,Component,,Dependency,,to,,Dependency to,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Component,0,,,,,
Class,quick,,,,Component,,Dependency,,from,,Dependency from,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Component,0,,,TRUE,,
Class,quick,Component,,,,,Dependency,,to,Dependency to,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,,,
Class,quick,Component,,,,,Dependency,,from,Dependency from,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,TRUE,,
Class,quick,Port,,,,,Dependency,,to,Dependency to,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,,,
Class,quick,Port,,,,,Dependency,,from,Dependency from,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,TRUE,,
Class,quick,Component,,,Port,,Dependency,,to,,Dependency to,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Port,0,,TRUE,,,
Class,quick,Component,,,Port,,Dependency,,from,,Dependency from,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Port,0,,TRUE,TRUE,,

I have then saved the UML Profile and generated an MDG from it. I have looked in the profile.xml and MDG xml files and in both cases the CSV information appears as I would expect in the QuickLink element:

e.g.

When I import the MDG, I can create a new diagram, the correct toolbox appears with my 'quick' stereotype on it. When I drag it onto the diagram however and try to create new links, the quicklinks menu is not showing any of my customisations.

Is there anythink I am missing here to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear to be the quicklinker definition. I have created a working technology using that definition (below).

It is likely that the problem is with the way the technology has been put together, rather than the quicklinks themselves. Hopefully you can see what is different by comparing this to your technology. If not then post your technology and I will take a look.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<UMLProfile profiletype="uml2">
 <Documentation id="C5186393-D" name="MyProfile" version="1.0" notes="MyProfile"/>
 <Content>
  <Stereotypes>
   <Stereotype name="quick" notes="">
    <AppliesTo>
     <Apply type="Class">
      <Property name="isActive" value=""/>
     </Apply>
    </AppliesTo>
   </Stereotype>
  </Stereotypes>
  <TaggedValueTypes/>
  <QuickLink data="Class,quick,,,,Component,,Dependency,,to,,Dependency to,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Component,0,,,,,&#xA;Class,quick,,,,Component,,Dependency,,from,,Dependency from,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Component,0,,,TRUE,,&#xA;Class,quick,Component,,,,,Dependency,,to,Dependency to,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,,,&#xA;Class,quick,Component,,,,,Dependency,,from,Dependency from,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,TRUE,,&#xA;Class,quick,Port,,,,,Dependency,,to,Dependency to,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,,,&#xA;Class,quick,Port,,,,,Dependency,,from,Dependency from,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,,0,,,TRUE,,&#xA;Class,quick,Component,,,Port,,Dependency,,to,,Dependency to,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Port,0,,TRUE,,,&#xA;Class,quick,Component,,,Port,,Dependency,,from,,Dependency from,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,Port,0,,TRUE,TRUE,,&#xA; &#xA;&#xA;"/>
 </Content>
</UMLProfile>
```